# Somando valor por valor em um array com Python

Tags: python, lista, loop

Preciso somar todos os valores possíveis dentro de um *array* para descobrir onde está um erro em um banco de dados.

Código até então:

```
valores = [50.70,1.80,121.37,100.00,3887.42,248.17,5650.31,702.00,556.90,54.77,2612.55,2414.05,1077.80,2612.55,47.90,535.56,1157.83,3116.31,250.00,780.00,1799.26,1732.09,2468.94,2612.55,715.50,550.00,600.00,890.52,1714.31,1714.61,150.35,2499.70,477.00,90.00,100.00,2412.12,3348.36,2612.55,47.00]
getValor = 0
soma = []
while getValor <= len(valores):
    soma[getValor] = valores[getValor] + valores[0]
    getValor = getValor + 1 
print(soma[getValor])
```

Eu repetiria esse *loop* para cada valor dentro do *array*, mudando o `valores[0]` para `valores[1]` e assim sucessivamente. Esse código retorna o erro:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Como faço? Quão errada está minha lógica?

Comment: `soma` foi declarada como uma lista vazia, então fazer `lista[0]` já retorna esse erro. Talvez o que você procure é a função `append()`, para adicionar um valor no final da lista. De qualquer maneira, tente utilizar o `for` no lugar do `while`, a implementação é bem mais simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito o que deseja seria algo assim:

```
valores = [50.70,1.80,121.37,100.00,3887.42,248.17,5650.31,702.00,556.90,54.77,2612.55,2414.05,1077.80,2612.55,47.90,535.56,1157.83,3116.31,250.00,780.00,1799.26,1732.09,2468.94,2612.55,715.50,550.00,600.00,890.52,1714.31,1714.61,150.35,2499.70,477.00,90.00,100.00,2412.12,3348.36,2612.55,47.00]
somas = []
for valor1 in valores:
    for valor2 in valores:
        somas.append(valor1 + valor2)
for valor in somas:
    print(valor)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zG98ZQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uooimifk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/CombinationArray.py).

Fiz isto com a lógica que parece indicar que é somar todas combinações possíveis (não eliminei as duplicações), e arrumei o problema que não estava crescendo a lista de somas com o método `append()`, e fiz da forma *pythonica* que não é usando `while` e sim pegando todos os valores de forma direta com `for`. Na verdade nem sei se precisa da lista de somas, só precisa mesmo se for fazer outras coisas com elas, caso contrário é só imprimir direto, muitas pessoas criam variáveis sem necessidade por desconhecerem a verdadeira vocação da [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, estou estudando o seu código enviado para pegar esse conhecimento lógico. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Python é uma linguagem que permite com que façamos as coisas de uma maneira mais facilitada. Dado seu array, uma forma simples e enxuta de safazer a soma usando uma baixa quantidade de variáveis e linhas seria assim:

```
for valor in valores:
    somas = [valor + val for val in valores]
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira *pythonica* de fazer isso é usando um recurso do Python chamado Compreensão de lista:

```
valores = [50.70,1.80,121.37,100.00,3887.42,248.17,5650.31,702.00,556.90,54.77,2612.55,2414.05,1077.80,2612.55,47.90,535.56,1157.83,3116.31,250.00,780.00,1799.26,1732.09,2468.94,2612.55,715.50,550.00,600.00,890.52,1714.31,1714.61,150.35,2499.70,477.00,90.00,100.00,2412.12,3348.36,2612.55,47.00]
soma = [(val_1 + val_2) for val_1 in valores for val_2 in valores]
for val in soma:
    print(val)
```

e caso não queira somar os elementos repetidos pode ser feito facilmente adicionado o `if`:

```
soma = [(val_1 + val_2) for val_1 in valores for val_2 in valores if val_1 != val_2]
```

Veja sobre [Compreensão de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `sum()` do python passando por parâmetro o array que deseja receber a soma.

Então se você utilizar `sum(valores)` ele te retorna o resultado.